# What do multiple columns of a record being set to unique mean?

Tags: records

Does the following mean that *both* columns or the *combination* of columns needs to be unique?

```
public function defineIndexes()
{
    return [
        ['columns' => ['productId', 'productTypeId'], 'unique' => true],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that no combination of those two columns can be the same in the table stated in the `getTableName()` of your record.